# Create custom reqacc.aspx for a site collection

Tags: 2007, accessibility

is there an easy way to point a single site collection to a custom reqacc.aspx page when users request access? This custom request form would be specific to one site collection within the portal. All other site collections would point to the original \Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\reqacc.aspx page.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this by creating a custom HTTP module and registering the same in the target web applications web.config file. Further you can override the beginrequest or endrequest method of the module and check for the URL of the request page. 
If the URL substring matches your site collection, you can then specify a redirection to a custom page.

Hope this help..